# How to use Krakenjs with Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, kraken.js

There are very few resources around krakenjs on the internet, and i can't find the right resource that shows how to do single page application with angularjs+nodejs+krakenjs.

can you please show me how to use those together or point me to some examples or resources?

Answer (score 1):

It works about the same as in Express, but you get to use Kraken's features to make express a little more approachable.

Kraken is almost entirely concerned with the server side, so making a single-page application is a separate thing. They only interface in that the kraken app will serve the landing page of your app -- possibly using the `/*` route hack to serve the app start page no matter the URL -- and may provide an API to talk to.

Comment: since kraken way of routing is based on controller's directory. how could you redirect * to index.html except some api requests like /api?

Comment: Use middleware after the router.